# MapStore in a Hazelcast Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, lifecycle, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast cluster that populates a distributed IMap with data from a separate, remote (REST) service.  I want to keep a local copy of the IMap data for HA/DR purposes so I implemented a file based MapStore.

It didn't work out like I expected.  I noticed that each node stores what is probably only the items in the partition of that node, which isn't necessarily a problem, but I also noticed that after a restart of all the nodes, the IMap only contains the items from the disk of the first node that starts up.

I couldn't find a good explanation in the docs about how the MapStore is used throughout the lifecycle of the nodes in a cluster.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The MapStore, as you figured out already, is called on nodes where the partition resides. Since the partition table is randomized on startup there is a very low chance to end up with the same partition distribution as on the last restart.

One way to work around this and still use your implementation is to introduce a distributed filesystem like Ceph or similar to store data files into. That way, no matter how partition table looks after the restart every node could read its partitions.